# Can file transfer speed be increased with an application when copy-pasting large amounts of data?

Tags: files, filemanager, paste

Are there transfer speed differences when a copy-paste action is done with different file managers?

Transfer [speed seem to vary within a single operation](https://askubuntu.com/q/575864/47206), but can a file manager or other application increase the speed of a copy-paste transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a file manager will have anything to do with speed. It more your read/write speed on the drive. your processor, memory and cache are factoring in there somewhere too.

If were talking USB drive, then we have to factor in  USB bandwidth and if anything shares the same bus (like a raspberry pi. USB and network use same bus, so if your transferring files remotely, to a USB drive there a bit of a bottleneck, but I digress)

Also, cut/paste tends to be faster, since it don't have to do all that pesky copying too.

Edit: I guess after further thought is possible may get better/worse performance from different file managers, but I think it would be so miniscule it wouldn't be noticed, unless something is pretty wrong with code of said file manager. The file managers may do things differently, but again, the speed difference would be minimal, I suspect.

Comment: In fact it seems that cut/paste is faster (in fact instantaneous) only when moving on the same partition (http://superuser.com/a/59611/162573 and http://superuser.com/a/434670/162573) as it only has to re-write the location of the file and not the file itself - while I am talking here of course about moving bit by bit on an external device by cut or copy.